# How to calculate end of week in SQL?

Tags: teradata

Given a date format yyyy-mm-dd, how would I calculate the saturday at the end of the week? For a sunday, I would like to calculate the saturday of the following week. I am using teradata 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the query on Saturday do you want to get the same day or the next Saturday?

```
next_day(date-1, 'sat')  -- same day

next_day(date, 'sat')    -- next Saturday
```